# Python 3.4 closing the main process after a Popen call

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

In my Python program I have a part where I need to re-load the script (Background edits are made).

I have the code that updates the python file and this is fine, I am using `Popen` (from `subproccess`) in order to start the new instance, and this works great!

However I want to close the main process, the one that actually called the subprocess afterwards. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I have tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("python test.py", creationflags=_winapi.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
sys.exit()
#os.execcl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
#os.execv(sys.executable, args)
```

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 10

**UPDATE**

So now I am using the below:

```
id = os.getpid()
os.system("TASKKILL /PID " + str(id) + " /F")
```

This does kill python but does not close the command prompt window afterwards, any idea how to do this? I've tried adding `&& exit` to the end of the taskkill but no luck.

Comment: And what doesn't work ?

Comment: The `sys.exit()` is not closing the main process

Comment: You're running Python from an instance of cmd. The console (conhost.exe) won't exit until all attached processes have exited, so you'd have to either kill the parent cmd shell or run python.exe directly from Explorer (e.g. double-click the script; a shortcut; or the Win+R run dialog) without involving the cmd shell.

Comment: `sys.exit` does close the main process, but it has to be called from the main thread. `os._exit` works from any thread, but it's an abrupt exit that won't run Python atexit functions.

Comment: FYI, `subprocess` has `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`; you don't have to use `_winapi`. But why do you need a new console? It would be cleaner to have the current process wait on the child, e.g. `sys.exit(p.wait())`, and leave the child attached to the current console. It would be even cleaner to also create a new Job for the child, configured to kill all processes in the Job if the parent exits, which, for example, is what py.exe does when it runs python.exe.